# Theos problems with g++ darwin9

Tags: ipad, ios5, g++, cydia

Hey guys im on ipad 2 3g ios 5.1.1
Anyway i tried compiling an app through theos and this is the problem
I find the helloworld directory with makefile and through terminal i type make
It says it's compiling but it then gives me this error

```
    /bin/sh: /usr/bin/arm-apple-darwin9-g++: no such file ir directory
    make [2] : *** [obj/main.mm.o] Error 127
    make [1] : *** [internal-tool-all_] Error 2
    make: *** [helloworld.all.tool.variables] Error 2
```

Using this theos template

```
    Choose template: 4 (iphone/tool)
    Project Name: helloworld
    Package Name: com.memyself.helloworld
    Author Maintainer Name: me myself
```

I get that its looking for arm-apple-darwin9-g++ in /usr/bin (i have arm-apple-darwin9-c++ in that directory)
But what is that and where do i get? Oh and what are those errors i dont get it at all help

Answer (score 0):

Thats easy,
Download the libgcc package from here http://apt.saurik.com/cydia/debs/libgcc_4.2-20080410-1-6_iphoneos-arm.deb and then install it. After that install the GNU C Compiler from Cydia and remember to put the headers in the var/theos/include directory. Good luck!

Comment: Now i get find.                                                     /bin/sh: /usr/theos/bin/ldid: Bad CPU type in executable
make [2] : *** [obj/helloworld] Error 126
make [1] : *** [internal-tool-all_] Error 2
make: *** [helloworld.all.tool.variables] Error 2